# Return first element while using reduce function

Tags: java, java-8, stream, java-stream, collectors

I am using reduce functionality of java stream.
My Stream data is as follows:

```
List<Person> persons =
        Arrays.asList(
            new Person("Max", 18),
            new Person("Peter", 23),
            new Person("Pamela", 23),
            new Person("David", 12),
            new Person("Pam", 23));
```

My Reduce function is as follows:

```
persons.stream()
            .reduce((p1, p2) -> p1.age > p2.age ? p1 : p2)
            .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

The result which i get is

> Pam

But my requirement is to element Peter as it also has the value greater than others.

> Peter

How can i achieve this? Any other alternate to do this?

Comment: Is it not p1 : p2 (or viceversa) instead of p2 : p2?

Comment: Yes its p1 : p2. Edited the question.

Comment: `.reduce((p1, p2) -> p1.age >= p2.age ? p1 : p2)`. Which is, by the way, the same as `.max(Comparator.comparing(p->p.age))` or, if you care for performance, `.max(Comparator.comparingInt(p->p.age))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try :

```
persons.stream()
        .reduce((p1, p2) -> p1.age >= p2.age ? p1 : p2)
        .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Note that I changed the condition from `p1.age > p2.age` to `p1.age >= p2.age`, so that an earlier `Person` instance having the same age as a later instance will be preferred.

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 2):

Simply reduce with the following rules:

For a given pair of people, `p1` and `p2`:

1. If `p1.age < p2.age`, result should be `p2`
2. If `p1.age > p2.age`, result should be `p1`
3. If `p1.age == p2.age`, result should be `p1`.

Easy implementation:

```
persons.stream()
            .reduce((p1, p2) -> p1.age < p2.age ? p2 : p1)
```

PS: your current code has a typeo and will always reduce to the last element in the list, ignoring the age comparison.